# Show that $P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)=1-(1-1/3)^3$

Tags: probability

Roll a fiar six-side die three times. Let:

$A_1=${ 1 or 2 on the 1st roll}

$A_2=${ 3 or 4 on the 2nd roll}

$A_3=${ 5 or 6 on the 3rd roll}

Given that:

$P(A_i)=1/3, i=1,2,3$

$P(A_i \cap A_i)=(1/3)^2, i\neq j$

$P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)=(1/3)^3 $

Show that $P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)=1-(1-1/3)^3$

This is what I have done so far:

$P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)+P(A_3)-P(A_1 \cap A_2)- P(A_1 \cap A_3)-P(A_2 \cap A_3)+ P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)=3(1/3)-3(1/3)^2+(1/3)^3=3(1/3)(1-1/3)+(1/3)^3=1-1/3+(1/3)^3=1-(1/3(1+(1/3)^2)$

This is where I got stuck. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The subscripts on $A$ have double meanings. If your **definitions** of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are taken literally, then $P(A_1 \cap A_2)\neq (1/3)^2)$.

Comment: why not? They are independent of each other.

Comment: You define $A_1$ as the event that the **first roll** results in a 1 or 2 and $A_2$ as the event that the **first roll** results in a 3 or a 4. These events are disjoint, not independent.

Comment: You are right. Sorry, that was a typing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$3(1/3)-3(1/3)^2+(1/3)^3=$$

$$3(1/3)-3*3*(1/3)(1/3)^2+(1/3)^3=$$

$$1-9(1/3)^3+(1/3)^3=$$

$$1-8(1/3)^3=$$

$$1-2^3(1/3)^3=$$

$$1-(2/3)^3=$$

$$1-(1-1/3)^3$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align*}(1-1/3)^3 &= {3\choose 0}1^3(-1/3)^0 + {3\choose 1}1^2(-1/3)^1 + {3\choose 2}1^1(-1/3)^2 + {3\choose 3}1= 0(-1/3)^3 \\
& = 1 - 1 + 3/3^2 - 1/3^3 \\
&= 1/3 - (1/3)^3
\end{align*}$$